# How do I control new tabs with Selenium WebDriver after they are opened?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to run different task on multiple firefox tabs. Each tab will load a different url at the start of the application. The a process one will run on a tab, go to next, run next tab, go to next tab etc. My issue is when I return to a tab that opened at application start up, I have to run driver.get(url) again in order to take control of that tab again. Is there a way to control a tab without have to run driver.get(url) all over again to control the page?

my code example:

```
main(){
      int ix = 1;
      while(ix <= numberOfTabstoRun){
        driver.get(url[ix]);
        if(ix != numberOfTabstoRun){
            openNewTab(driver);
        }

        ix++;
      }

      /**THIS WONT WORK - can't control next tab**/
      while(true){
        //run process on open tab
        nextTab(driver);
      }


      /**I am forced to do this**/
      int x = 1;
      while(true){
        driver.get(url[x]);
        //run process on open tab
        nextTab(driver);
        x++;
      }

}



private void openNewTab(WebDriver driver){
    new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t")).perform();
}

private void nextTab(WebDriver driver){
    new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.TAB)).perform();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch the driver to the new target after you send the `ctrl+tab`.

```
private void nextTab(WebDriver driver){
    new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.TAB)).perform();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

More details at http://design-interviews.blogspot.com/2014/11/switching-between-tabs-in-same-browser-window.html

Comment: driver.switchTo().defaultContent() is the ticket.  Took me forever to find this.  Thanks!